Proving The Inverse Triangle Inequality Theorem
My professor gave us a question to prove the triangle inequality theorem.The eact question is as follows:For x, y ∈ R, prove that ||x| − |y|| ≤ |x − y|, (Hint: consider x = y + (x − y)). I have attached my 3 page proof of how I proved this inequality.Can someone go through it and tell me if I attempted it correctly?(P.S I did not follow the  hint given)(Also I could not attach the images becasue I do not have enough reputatuion)
Page 1:[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MBSUsTyp.jpg
Page 2:[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/2CWx8XM6.jpg
Page 3:[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/IYRwXSIW.jpg

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

$3$ pages to prove the reverse triangle inequality seems overkill

The hint and the triangle inequality should be enough. Assuming $|x| \geq |y|$, then $||x| - |y|| = |x| - |y| = |y + (x-y)| - |y|.$ Can you see what to do from there?

You have not proved the inequality, since you started your proof with the assumption that the inequality is true. A proof by contradiction would instead start by assuming:
$$||x|-|y|| > |x-y|$$
And would then do the exact same steps as you have done, except that in the end the inequality will hold false for all cases.
Alternatively, you could work backwards by first proving that $xy \le |x||y|$ holds for all cases, and then through step-by-step manipulation:
$$-2xy \ge -2|x||y|$$
$$x^2-2xy+y^2 \ge |x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2$$
$$(x-y)^2 \ge (|x|-|y|)^2$$
$$|x-y| \ge ||x|-|y||$$
